# Safari and IE can't read TTF and EOT fonts

Tags: css, safari, cross-browser, font-face, truetype

1. I have trouble reading a font in Safari. I converted OTF to TTF - two bold and regular fonts. Both are fine in Chrome and Firefox. But in Safari, only the bold font is works, regular does not.
2. IE does not read the EOT font which I have converted from a website. Is there any better way to convert OTF to EOT?

Here is my code:

```
<style type="text/css">
//Bariol_Bold
@font-face{
    font-family: Bariol_Bold;
    src:url("fonts/bariol_bold.eot"); /*For ie browser*/
}

@font-face{ 
    font-family: Bariol_Bold;
    src:url("fonts/bariol_bold.ttf"); /*For other browsers*/
}

//Bariol_Regular
@font-face{
    font-family:bariol_regular;
    src:url("fonts/bariol_regular.eot"); /*For ie browser*/
}

@font-face{ 
    font-family: bariol_regular;
    src:url("fonts/bariol_regular.ttf"); /*For other browsers*/  
</style>

<p style="font-family: Bariol_Bold; font-size: 20px;">hello world</p>
<p style="font-family: bariol_regular; font-size: 20px;">hello world</p>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should check [Paul Irish's Bulletproof `@font-face` Syntax](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) or [FontSpring's `@font-face` Syntax](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax) which needs multiple declarations of the the same font in different file types to server multiple browsers.

The basic declaration is like

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
  src: url('myfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
   url('myfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
   url('myfont-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
   url('myfont-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
```

I also prefer [FontSquirrel's `@font-face` Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) but you can Google other alternatives. FontSquirrel just needs one font to be converted and it will provide you with a basic `.zip` file that contains necessary font types plus a sample demo of the fonts generated.