# Font Face not working completely in Safari

Tags: css, internet-explorer, safari

I am using the Font Face Property and I have tested it in Firefox, Chrome and Opera...it works fine. 
however when I try it in safari and explorer it only works on one line and not the other

here is the css :

```
 @font-face { 
     font-family: font2;
     src:url(../fonts/Artbrush.TTF) ;
 } 

@font-face { 
    font-family: font1;
    src :url(../fonts/playbiln.TTF) ;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem before. what happens is that the ttf fonts do not usually work well on mac / safari

[Safari and IE can't read TTF and EOT fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889045/safari-and-ie-cant-read-ttf-and-eot-fonts)

Comment: Thank you very much...this helped alot..it seams that safari reads Woff fonts

Answer (score 25):

changing `font-style: italic;` in my `@fontface` declarations in the css file to (even though what was being used was an italic, oblique font) `font-style: normal;`... on the italic fonts mind you...

Safari now displays them fine and it doesn't seem to break other browsers for this mismatched work-around.

Comment: this fixed it for me -- typekit was producing a CSS @font-face rule for a font that used `font-style:italic` and that broke it for Safari - changing to `font-style:normal` fixed it (specifically the font was Eloquent JF Pro)

Comment: yes, as said, if you already load an Italic Font, the css style rule should be just normal

Comment: Thanks so much for this. scratching my head over for this problem

Comment: I can't thank you enough for posting this answer! I couldn't figure out why Safari refused to download a recursive font I added for my Angular project.

Answer (score 3):

## Easy fix

For me, adding `font-weight: 1 1000;` property made it work for safari as well. In-appropriate font-weights are now fixed.

```scss
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Inter var', sans-serif;
  src: url('/fonts/Inter-roman-latin.var.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: 1 1000;
}
```

- One more benefit is, you don't need to check for the `@support`.
- To be more cautious, please check [MDN Docs for font-weight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight#browser_compatibility)