# Variable font not loading properly in Safari

Tags: css, webfonts, variable-fonts

I'm using a variable font, and it is working correctly on Chrome (Version 97.0.4692.71) and Firefox (96.0.2) but not on Safari (15.1).

On CSS, I'm importing the font like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Bild V3 Variable Web';
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('fonts/BildVariableV3-VF.woff2') format('woff2-variations'),
    url('fonts/BildVariableV3-VF.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-weight: 100 900;
}
```

And using it like this:

```
h2 {
    font-family: Bild Variable V3;
    font-variation-settings: "wght" 300;
    font-size: 72px;
    color: $white;
}
```

Does anyone have a clue on why this is happening?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24679822/10301322) help for your issue?

Comment: font-variation-settings is not supported on Safari see https://caniuse.com/?search=font-variation-settings

Comment: I added the font-weight instead of font-variations-settings, but still not working :(