# Fonts are not loading but URL is pointing well

Tags: html, css, fonts

I installed the "Recoleta" and "HK Grotesk" fonts on [my website](http://humblyhejb.cluster020.hosting.ovh.net/) but both fonts are not loading on all devices and all browsers (specially Safari, as some people said it often loads on Chrome/Firefox).

I don't understand as the relative URLs are pointing well when I try them.

I'm using Gulp & Scss to compile my css (my fonts are in an original fonts.scss file compiled in a final app.css file).

I tried changing the position of fonts.scss (beginning/middle/end of app.scss) but doesn't change anything.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Recoleta', serif;
  src: url('../fonts/recoleta/Recoleta-Medium.woff') format('woff');
  src: url('../fonts/recoleta/Recoleta-Medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/recoleta/Recoleta-Medium.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/recoleta/Recoleta-Medium.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'HK Grotesk', sans-serif;
  src: url('../fonts/hk-grotesk/HKGrotesk-Bold.woff2') format('woff2');
  src: url('../fonts/hk-grotesk/HKGrotesk-Bold.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/hk-grotesk/HKGrotesk-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/hk-grotesk/HKGrotesk-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: 400;
  font-display: swap;
}
```

This is the expected result : https://ibb.co/MRMk1jM

Comment: This might help -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889045/safari-and-ie-cant-read-ttf-and-eot-fonts

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to remove the 'serif' or 'sans-serif' in the font-family.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Recoleta';
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'HK Grotesk';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@vbernet Kindly, try to genrate the fonts files from this website: (https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) and then implement it. I think one of the font file type is missing which support to safari browser.

Comment: The answer is just above actually ;). I needed to remove the 'sans-serif' from font -family.